# Like Selenium grid (hub & node), is there any option to run KarateDriver on grid

Tags: karate

I had implemented KarateDriver and it is faster implementation. Thanks for the great framework. Just wondering if there is a way I can run Karate driver across the multiple nodes the way we do selenium hub and tests run on nodes. If so, how would I design features and do multithreading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is great to hear thanks. Have you seen this wiki page: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/Distributed-Testing

> In 0.9.5 onwards Karate can split a test-suite across multiple nodes that can be running remotely. This means that you can run Web-UI automation in parallel but get a single consolidated report which includes video of each Scenario.

We are proposing a different model for distributing Karate tests. Would be great to get your feedback and contributions if possible, thanks.

Comment: Thank you for sharing the answer. I am also trying RaspberryPi clusters for light weight API automation PoC. Considering the fact that newer version of Raspi is 3 times faster than previous version 3. This is great info

Comment: It sounds to me, by this answer, that the reason for not implementing Grid is all due to the need to collate/collect the test report data?   Is there a problem with that working when tests are running on Grid?

Comment: I did read it:  I can think of no reason why you didn't choose to just run against a Grid and then download videos from the grid to the test-report rather than doing a custom Docker container.  Don't get me wrong, I love Docker.  Just not understanding the need to re-invent your own distributed-testing mechanism when Grid already existed with the distributed capability you need.  Just seems like a step backward to me.  For example: wouldn't you want to have compatibility with SauceLabs and Browserstack/Appium?

Comment: @djangofan ah I get it, you think the term "Grid" is a monopoly of the S_lenium project :P ok jokes aside, the Karate approach does *not* require you to run an "always-on" master node and it is a superior model in my (biased) opinion. it is designed so that in most cases, teams can run this as a *normal* Jenkins job. time will tell if it is a "step backward", fair ?

Comment: Ok, I see what you mean.  I see where you are coming from: saving money by having on-demand instances.  But, other people have solved that in a better way, such as https://aerokube.com/selenoid/latest/   or https://opensource.zalando.com/zalenium/ .    Why not integrate with Selenoid or Zalenium instead?

Comment: @djangofan nope, Selenoid is just the same "Grid" in a new bottle, it doesn't change the whole model like we are trying. it is not just about on-demand instances, it is the ease by which someone can run a distributed test without extra setup. look at the last paragraph of the wiki, we solved Gatling distributed testing with the same architecture and it will work for normal JUnit actually come to think of it. I think I already said to you elsewhere that Karate implements the WebDriver W3C spec so if someone does the minimal work to validate / close gaps, it will work with "Grid" and "S_uceLbs".